# How to convert a date with timezone to Javascript ISO format?

Tags: go

I am trying to convert this date string ("2018-10-29T11:48:09.180022-04:00") to ISO format in Go. But not able to do. Can anyone help?

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    l,_ := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00", "2018-10-29T15:18:20-04:00")
    fmt.Println(l, time.Now(), time.Now().UTC().Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"))
}
```

Output:

```
2018-10-29 15:18:20 -0400 -0400 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001 2009-11-10T23:00:00Z
```

https://play.golang.org/p/gXw39_Y-hpR

Comment: "But not able to do" why? What problem are you having?

Comment: Updated the question with output @Adrian

Comment: OK. What's the problem with the output? Please specify what issue you're having.

Comment: For that matter, what's the problem with the input string? Your date string is *already in* ISO 8601 format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your input string is valid [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

However, for JSON serialization, JavaScript uses a slightly different (but still completely valid) style of ISO 8601 date format in which only 3 digits are used for fractional seconds (giving millisecond resolution) and the timezone is adjusted to [Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)), (aka GMT+0, or "Zulu" timezone) designated with a `Z`.

```
// JavaScript
JSON.stringify(new Date()); // => "2018-10-30T15:22:30.293Z"
// Millisecond resolution ─────────────────────────────┺┻┛┃
// "Zulu" (UTC) time zone ────────────────────────────────┚
```

You can convert your timestamp into the JavaScript style by first parsing the input string, then converting to Zulu time via the [`UTC()` method](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.UTC), then formatting with the desired output format.

For example ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/lho-8DHDRVk)):

```
const (
  INPUT_FORMAT  = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999-07:00"
  OUTPUT_FORMAT = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"
)

func timestampToJavaScriptISO(s string) (string, error) {
  t, err := time.Parse(INPUT_FORMAT, s)
  if err != nil {
    return "", err
  }
  return t.UTC().Format(OUTPUT_FORMAT), nil
}

func main() {
  s := "2018-10-29T11:48:09.180022-04:00"
  s2, err := timestampToJavaScriptISO(s)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  fmt.Println(s2)
  // 2018-10-29T15:48:09.180Z
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can just convert it by using the RFC3339 format:

```
 unitTimeInRFC3339 :=time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)
```

Comment: `time.Now().Unix()` gives *seconds* since the epoch, not ms, and the question asked how to convert "to ISO format", not to milliseconds or seconds.